Can't access udev even as root user
I tried this command:
sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
But still got Permission denied
Tried to login as root user,but still didn't work.
Please help.

The output of command namei -l /etc/udev/rules.d/60-vboxadd.rules may be helpful

Check the file's ownership with:
ls -l /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

If it's not root, change it:
sudo chown root:root /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Then, set the correct permissions:
sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

If still denied, check if the file is locked:
sudo lsof /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Ensure the file system is not read-only:
mount | grep '/etc'
sudo mount -o remount,rw /etc

Reboot if needed:
sudo reboot

I am not very knowledgeable about this as I have never experienced this problem. Hopefully this works!

For this sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules I see the permissions of 644 for files in that udev folder. Did you use the one you gave?
